# How to encrypt the data and open PDF in new tab when user click on link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, pdf

when i user this window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + (response.fileContent));

the problem with this is its opening browser tab like in address bar data://encrypted data. i want to display there file name instead of it.

Can you please help me with this.

Comment: What is purpose of changing the title the document?

Comment: not clear sentences.

Comment: What is not clear?

Comment: The way i posted question for answer was not cleat in text so.

Comment: The data is not encrypted. That is the `<data>` portion of a `data URI`. Why do you need to set the `document.title`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have encrypted data coming from back-end . so what i am doing is it with decrypted that data and opening it in new tab . is that wrong ? . can you please let me know what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. The data appears to be a `data URI`, not encrypted data. You can actually wrap the `data URI` which is a `.pdf` within an HTML `document` to set the `document.title`

Answer (score 0):

To set the `document.title` where the document is actually a [`data URI`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) you can use an HTML `document` and set an `<iframe>` `src` to the `data URI` of the `.pdf`

```
var data = `data:application/pdf;base64,${response.fileContent}`;

var title = "abc.pdf";

var html = `data:text/html,
           <!DOCTYPE html>
           <html>
             <head>
               <title>${title}</title>
             </head>
             <body>
               <iframe src=${data} width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>
             </body>
           </html>`;

var w = window.open(html);
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/8gS7gBOEMPLjzqByMe4Z?p=preview